# How to open new page and send to it POST data?

Tags: java

From current JSP I need to open new page with sending to it POST data. How I can make it?

In other words I need redirect from one page to another, but I cant use sendRedirect(because only GET) and requestDispatcher(because context of pages are different)

Comment: This will help: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt

Comment: You answer is written down in everey html-beginner book and tutorial. Please consider to read a small piece of documentaion before you ask trivial questions. (You need a <form> element with a name attribute.) This questions is not about java or jsp but about html.

Comment: I need make it using Java inside JSP.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create `<form method="post">`, fill the fields with respective data and submit it by JavaScript.

But on the other hand, what is your reason for that? There probably exists a cleaner solution.

Comment: thanks, But I cant use html for this purpose, I need make it inside JSP.

Comment: JSP outputs HTML - or you want to do a redirect?

Comment: @RanRag , I know what mean JSP :)  In other words I need redirect from one page to another, but I cant use sendRedirect(because only GET) and requestDispatcher(because context of pages are different)

Answer (score -1):

Just make the behaviour that would happen if the initial POST data is received the default behaviour of the JSP when no post data is received.

e.g (in pseudo code - I don't know Java)

```
if (is_set(POST) ) {
   if(POST == expectedInitialVals) {
       defaultBahaviour();
   } else {
       handleOtherValues();
   }

} else {
   defaultBahaviour();
}
```

If you also want to persist the POST data in the page set the values on the relevant form fields in the page in your JSP.

Comment: you don't understand question.. I need using Java code (inside JSP) open new page from existing page, but with sending POST data to this new page.